# Hyperlinks cannot be opened in Google drive documents in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-drive, hyperlink

I am trying to open a hyperlink in a pdf file located in google drive (My browser is Google Chrome) but for some reason it does not allow me to open it. But If I try to open in an incognito window I can open it. Also if I download that pdf file I can open the hyperlink and also I can open it through another browser. I believe there is some issue with my google account or google chrome.

I reinstalled it, updated it and cleared the cache but the problem is still there.

I think this issue appeared today when I clicked accidentally something related with extensions but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not caused by the browser. The problem resides probably in Google Docs.

If you `logout` of your Google account, the link will work.

Just go to [google.com](https://www.google.com/) and logout.

It's a bug in Google Docs Web App. I sent feedback. I hope they'll fix it soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149833/discussion-between-toni-and-rfz).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, a thread that has me coming in early enough into an issue, that I can add to the thread before it's solved.  Unfortunately, I have not enough reputation to make a comment.  This definitely isn't an answer, but hopefully it helps point people in a direction while I continue investigating on my end.

I'm having the exact same issue, links inside an embedded PDF file are not clickable, the cursor doesn't change, it's like it doesn't even render with the links available at all.  That said, it's something to do with being signed in to a Google account.

My work uses Google for their accounts.  So far, my setup & experience has been:

- Chrome signed in to work Google account
- Firefox signed in to personal GMail account
- Edge not signed in to anything
- Chrome fails to render the embedded PDF properly, no links available.  If I open Chrome as Incognito, it works immediately.
- Firefox fails to render the embedded PDF properly, no links available.  If I open Firefox as a Private window, it works immediately.
- Edge loads the site correctly, with clickable links in the embedded PDF file, regardless of being a normal window or Incognito.
- The moment I went to Google.com, within Edge, and signed in to my work Google account, the embedded PDF file broke and links were not showing up.

The embedded file itself, belongs to a coworker.  They have the PDF saved in their Google Drive, and it is embedded inside a Google Site page.

Will update further, if/when I find out more, if people don't add on before then.

Comment: Reached out to Google Support, and have been working with their engineering team (supplying examples, log files, screen recordings, etc).  Seems to be working better now, though they haven't explicitly stated that they're done working on it on their end.